# Timestamp related in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

In a Postgres database I have a table that in one of its columns holds a date as a *character varying* data type. Its format is `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm`.

Eg.: `21 Sep 2012 12:23`.

Is there a way to convert it in a timestamp fromat so that I can compare it with the current time (i.e. `now()`- function ) ?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html
Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `to_timestamp` function:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('21 Sep 2012 12:23', 'DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/785

Comment: I'm sure that you do not want to use `HH` but `HH24`.

Comment: @A.H. Thank you, I didn't even know HH12 is the default.

Answer (score 4):

There are `SET DATA TYPE` and `USING` parts to the `ALTER TABLE` statement. If you wanted to fix the column permanently.

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ALTER COLUMN my_time_stamp SET DATA TYPE timestamp
    USING to_timestamp(my_time_stamp);
```

See [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html)

Comment: I need it to stay a character varying data type. Anyway, as A.H. mentiond very good pointed.

Answer (score 2):

I had somewhere read about to_timestamp 
try this out `to_timestamp(text, text)`

```
functionname:---to_timestamp(text, text)    
returntype---timestamp with time zone 
its function---convert string to time stamp
```

example: `to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY')`